# Create a theme over themed in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, themes

I need to create a separate theme in **Cakephp** which only changes one view file. But the fact is that this is already themed. There is some personalization in themes. Is there any way to create themes inside themes in **CakePHP**?

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can create parallel themes, and then just link your one view to the second theme. Let's say you have the following theme right now:

`/app/View/Themed/MyTheme`

...and you only want to change the view file for the `Users::Login` action which would be here:

`/app/View/Themed/MyTheme/Users/login.ctp`

Create a 2nd Theme Folder, and `login.ctp` which your overwrite your main theme file:

`/app/View/Themed/MyOtherTheme/Users/login.ctp`

Now in your Controller action, in this case `UsersController::login()`, change the theme being used for the action:

```
public function myFunction() {
  $this->theme = 'MyOtherTheme';
}
```